# Unable to run go install with private gitlab repo

Tags: git, docker, go, gitlab

I'm trying to build a docker image of a go server. The source code is on gitlab.com.
Based on this tuto i added git config in my Dockerfile

```
#Start from a Debian image with the latest version of Go installed

FROM golang:latest

ENV READIUM_LICENSE_CONFIG /config/config.yaml
ENV REPO=gitlab.com/gara-project/back-end-micro-services/lcp-server/readium-lcp-server

ADD src /src
ADD lcp-server/entrypoint.sh /entrypoint.sh

RUN git config \
  --global \
  url."https://username:token@gitlab.com".insteadOf \
  "https://gitlab.com"
RUN GIT_TERMINAL_PROMPT=1


RUN GOPATH=/ go install $REPO@latest

RUN chmod a+x /entrypoint.sh

VOLUME ["/files", "/config"]

CMD ["/bin/lcpserver"]
ENTRYPOINT ["/entrypoint.sh"]

EXPOSE 8989
```

The username and token is correct, because i try a git clone on with it.
When I run the build of the docker file I got

> go install
> gitlab.com/gara-project/back-end-micro-services/lcp-server/readium-lcp-server@latest: module
> gitlab.com/gara-project/back-end-micro-services/lcp-server/readium-lcp-server:
> git ls-remote -q origin in
> /pkg/mod/cache/vcs/389aeee014594569659e179bbd3e2519e3cd572a0adc7faf372d5fdbcb7d22bd:
> exit status 128:
> remote: The project you were looking for could not be found.
> fatal: repository 'https://xxxx:xxxxxx@gitlab.com/gara-project/back-end-micro-services.git/'
> not found

1- I don't know why go is looking for `gara-project/back-end-micro-services.git` instead of looking for
`gitlab.com/gara-project/back-end-micro-services/lcp-server/readium-lcp-server`
2- How could i set my go to access my gitlab ? I tried many solution without success.

Thank

Answer (score -2):

I have run into the same problem:

```
go install gitlab.com/foo/bar/baz@latest
go install: gitlab.com/foo/bar/baz@latest: module gitlab.com/foo/bar/baz: git ls-remote -q origin in /Users/user/go/pkg/mod/cache/vcs/<hash>: exit status 128:
    remote: The project you were looking for could not be found or you don't have permission to view it.
    fatal: repository 'https://gitlab.com/foo/bar.git/' not found
```

Clearly, `go install` isn't looking in the right place.

What has been recommended:

- Setting `go env -w "GOPRIVATE=gitlab.com/foo/*"` (to get `go` to look in the "right" places)
- Setting `~/.netrc` to have `machine gitlab.com username <USERNAME> password <GITLAB_PAT>`, OR
- Setting `~/.gitconfig` to have:

```
[url "ssh://git@gitlab.com/"]
    insteadOf = https://gitlab.com/
```

As recommended in: https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-foss/-/issues/65681 and https://go.dev/doc/faq#git_https

However, none of these solutions currently work for me.

Comment: Downvoting just since this answer doesn't provide any sort of solution - just more things that don't work. If you want to provide extra context for OP, that's a good use case for commenting.